# ¿Cómo enviar un mensaje toast si no acetpta el "getApplicationContext()"?

Tags: android-studio, adapter, android-context, android-toast

Tengo un problema al intentar enviar un mensaje toast para cuando el usuario toque algún elemento de mi lista creada mediante un `RecyclerView`. Por lo que entiendo se necesita un contexto para poderlo hacer, y se resolvería con un "extends AppCompatActivity" el problema es que mi clase adaptador ya no lo acepta porque no sé puede usar mas de una vez. ¿Tienen alguna idea de cómo lo podría resolver?

```
public class AdatadorListaAlumnos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdatadorListaAlumnos.ViewHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static  class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView NombreCompleto;
        ImageView ImagenAlumno;

        public List<Alumno> alumnosLista;
        public AdatadorListaAlumnos(List<Alumno>alumnosLista){
            this.alumnosLista = alumnosLista;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder (ViewHolder holder, final int position) {  
            holder.NombreCompleto.setText(alumnosLista.get(position).getNombres() + 
                       " " + alumnosLista.get(position).getApellidos());  
            holder.ImagenAlumno.setImageResource(alumnosLista.get(position).getImagen());

        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() /*No lo acepta*/,"Id: "
            +alumnosLista.get(position).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido...

Tienes que pasar el contexto desde la actividad (Si es el caso) que vas mostrar el `Toast`. Intenta lo siguiente:

```
public class AdatadorListaAlumnos extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    Context mContext; // Declara aquí

    // Constructor
    public AdatadorListaAlumnos(List<Alumno>alumnosLista, Context context){
         this.alumnosLista = alumnosLista;
         this.mContext = context;
    }

...

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Id: " + alumnosLista.get(position).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Para aplicarlo lo usas así:

```
mAdapter = new AdatadorListaAlumnos(alumnoList, this);
```

Espero que sea de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Fabian, muchas gracias por responder. Lo acabo de intentar pero me sigue marcando error :(. En la parte de "this" dice que AdatadorListaAlumnos no puede ser aplicado, lo cambié por "mContext " y en el logcat manda esto "constructor AdatadorListaAlumnos in class AdatadorListaAlumnos cannot be applied to given types;
        adatadorListaAlumnos = new AdatadorListaAlumnos(sqLiteDb.mostrarAlumnos());
                               ^
  required: List<Alumno>,Context
  found: List<Alumno>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error" :'(. Tienes alguna idea?

Comment: Al parecer te falta un parámetro del constructor `AdaptadorListaAlumnos`. El error que te da dice que requiere como parámetros `List<Alumno>` y `Context` o sea 2, pero que encuentra solo un `List<Alumno>` quiere decir que te falta pasar el contexto (el 2do parámetro). Fíjate en la última parte de mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Fabian tienes razón, encontré el error. Lo que pasa es que de otra clase que tengo sólo pasaba un parámetro y noté que ahí era donde  debía construir el Toast